# Undoing Select-All in Chrome on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, google-chrome, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

For work, I'm usually using `tmux` on PuTTY on my Windows Desktop. Because of that, I'm use to doing <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd>. Sometimes, I'm accidentally on Chrome when I press that keycombo. This selects all text on screen.

Other that moving over to the mouse and clicking somewhere on the window, what would be the best way (quick keycombo?) to "Select none" just using *just* the keyboard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pressing Tab once or twice seems to clear the selection. Of course, this also moves the focus to another link or field. You might be able to do Tab then Shift Tab if that's a problem.